# Properties of preimage of critical values of a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

My question is very vague and poorly stated. Let $f: M \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function with $M$ a smooth manifold. Let $y \in \mathbb{R}$ be a critical value which isn't a global extremum. We know in general that $f^{-1}(y)$ isn't necessarily a submanifold of $M$, but I'm wondering if there are cases where it still is, or at least is "almost" a manifold.

To be more clear about what I'm saying I'll give an example that's easy to visualize. Say $M$ is a compact surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $f$ is the height function. For a regular value $x$, the preimage of it will look like a set of circles (if I'm not wrong). I think of it as the intersection of the surface with the plane $z=x$

For a critical value $y$ that isn't a global max or min (say it is the peak of some hill), the preimage will consist of a point as well as at least one circle. This is because $f^{-1}(y)$ not only has a critical point, but also a set of regular points which map to the circle, let's say.

How do we describe this preimage, is it still a manifold? It has components of different dimensions, does this contradict the definition? Can we say that removing the critical points of the preimage leaves us with a properly defined manifold?

Comment: I'm not qualified enough to answer, but I think you might find what you're looking for in [Morse theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_theory)

Comment: I skimmed through the relevant chapters of Milnor's classic book, and unless I missed it, I couldn't find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a theorem in Lee's *Introduction to smooth manifolds* which states that for all closed subset $K$ of a smooth manifold $M$, there is a smooth function $f:M\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f^{-1}(0)=K$ (!). So there is no hope in the general case to put structure on the preimage of any critical value.

But you can ask your function to be Morse, that is every critical point is non-degenerate, i.e. you can find coordinates $\varphi:U\to\mathbb{R}^n,p\mapsto (x_1(p),\dots,x_n(p))$ centered on each critical point $c\in U$ such that in these coordinates,

$$f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=f(c)+x_1^2+\dots+x_k^2-x_{k+1}^2-\dots-x_n^2.$$

This tells you that the preimage of a critical value of a Morse function is locally homeomorphic either to an euclidean space (near regular points of the sublevel) or to a $0$-level set of a quadric (near critical points of the sublevel).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What do you mean by sublevel? I don't quite follow the last statement.

Comment: What I call "sublevel" or "level sets" are the sets $f^{-1}(y)$ for $y\in\mathbb{R}$. The last statement deals with the two kind of points you can find in them, the critical and the regular ones (eg in a regular level set, that is $f^{-1}(v)$ with $v$ a regular value of $f$, you can only find regular ones).

Comment: Oh so does this mean that the subset of regular points of a level set (even the level set of a critical value) is a submanifold? (when $f$ is a Morse function)

Comment: Yes, since the manifold without the critical point is an open set of your initial manifold (and so a manifold of the same dimension), and on this one the map $f$ has constant rank $1$. Then the constant-rank level set theorem tells you that each sublevel is a manifold of codimension $1$ (or codimension $k$ if the target is a manifold $N$ of dimension $k$).

Comment: Alright that clarifies a lot, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: (Note that this is indeed true exclusively in the case where $f$ is Morse: if $f$ isn't, the set of critical points can be awful and $M$ without these points is perhaps not even a manifold).

Comment: This is because the critical points of a Morse function are isolated, right?

Comment: Yes, precisely.